# «Оставить в покое» — фразеологизм?

Tags: фразеология, классификация

Скажите, пожалуйста, является ли выражение «оставить в покое» фразеологизмом?

Answer (score 4):

Можно утверждать, что это **устойчивое** словосочетание, а относить ли его к *фразеологизмам* - это зависит от используемого определения фразеологизма (фразеологической единицы). Общепринятой классификации нет. Проблема в том, что в нашем случае смысл выражения почти буквален и выводится из входящих в него слов. По классификации Виноградова, на которую ссылается "Википедия", устойчивый оборот можно рассматривать как "фразеологическое выражение" (частный случай фразеологизма) уже на основании того, что оно является готовой речевой единицей. По другим классификациям - этого недостаточно, см. напр. статью "Фразеологические единицы как объект исследования...": https://cyberleninka.ru/article/v/frazeologicheskie-edinitsy-kak-obekt-issledovaniya-v-trudah-otechestvennyh-issledovateley

В нашем случае выражение, помимо своего буквального значения (как в императиве "*оставьте меня в покое* = не беспокойте ненужными мне вопросами, не приставайте, не отвлекайте"), может иногда использоваться в переносном смысле (*"оставим в покое эту тему"*), но и этот смысл остаётся прозрачным и далёким от *идиоматического*, свойственного основной массе фразеологизмов. Поэтому вывод зависит от принимаемой классификации.

Comment: Согласен с Вами. Сам бы в жизни не посчитал это ярко выраженным фразеологизмом, но словари, увы, имеют другие соображения на этот счёт.

Answer (score 2):

Да. По крайней мере, так заявляют два фразеологических словаря:

> Оставить в покое — (иноск.) не трогать, не мешать Оставь меня в покое! убирайся, не трогай, не мешай Ср. Так лучше бы ты мертвых ел И оставлял живых в покое. Крылов. Медведь в сетях …

**Большой толково-фразеологический словарь Михельсона**

> Оставлять/оставить в покое Переставать беспокоить кого-либо или что-либо, докучать кому-либо. Оставлять в покое кого? человека, ребенка, детей, родителей…

**Е. А. Быстрова**